# Git merge strategy for a release branch

Tags: git, git-flow, cicd

Our workflow is kind of GitFlow-inspired. But because we use GitHub we do not use actual GitFlow CLI helpers, and do things manually.

Our current workflow is:

- Checkout new branches off of `master`
- Merge PRs into `master`
- Our CI process deploys from `production` branch
- When we want to release, we create a PR from `release/*` branch, into `production`.
- Sometimes we need to hotfix and we merge the hotfix into `master`, and then cherry-pick commits into `production`.

So the problem is that when we cherry-pick hotfixes into `production` branch, then we cannot cleanly merge the release branch, as it may contain commits out of order and we get a ton of merge conflicts.

I am wondering if there is a git merge strategy that can help with this? I've looked at the docs, but it is still pretty confusing.

Ideally, the way I see it, I just want to play back every commit one by one, onto a `production` branch, and if the commit was already applied, it'd be skipped.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: When you merge a hotfix branch into production, do you also merge it into master? And into any current release branches?

Comment: Every hotfix goes thru a normal PR process. Meaning that it lands into master. Then from the master, we cherry-pick it onto the production branch. There are usually no release branches in motion.

Comment: I think you can do better without the cherry-pick thing. Merge the hotfix directly into production, then also merge into master. Then release branches created from there will already have the hotfix. You cannot get rid of every single conflict, but it can help minimize. After all, out of order merges will stil happen, no matter what source control you use.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create two PRs one into master and one into production?

Comment: Yes, merge twice, once into each branch. This is the suggested approach in the GitFlow diagrams, that quickly merges hotfixes into produccion and also integrates the fix into development branches. Future merges from dev to prod will already have the fix.